# How do bool comparison operators work in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ programming . Please, can someone explain to me how bool comparison operators work in user-defined data types?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class person {
public:
    float age;
    string name;

    bool operator<(const person& rhs) const
    {
        return age < rhs.age;
    }

    bool operator>(const person& rhs) const
    {
        return age > rhs.age;
    }
};
```

Comment: They're explained in your book. No need to repeat its contents here.

Comment: By the way, those are not particularly good comparison operator implementations for that class.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? What's wrong with what you've already implemented?

Comment: It's an operator that returns a `bool`. `true` if the relation holds, `false` if it doesn't.

Comment: Look up tutorials on *operator overloading*.

Comment: They don't necessarily have to be `bool` operators. For user-defined types, you can define the behaviour of the operator function and it can return any type. What part is it that's not clear to you?

Comment: It would take far too long to explain all the details of operator overloading. If that's what you want then you should look at a C++ book. On the other hand if you have a *specific* question or doubt you should explain what that is. That kind of question can be easily answered.

Comment: Doesn't directly address the question, but worthwhile reading all the same: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: What do you not understand?  (It is unclear what you are having trouble with in your question.)  Are you learning C++ from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Answer (score 2):

C++ standard provides a better way to use the operators directly with objects. For example:

```
class abc {
public:
    abc() {}
};

// declaration
abc a1, a2, a3;
a3 = a1 + a2; // impossible expression without operator overload
```

Here, you can't use arithmetic operator `+`, since they're objects of the type of `abc` class and the expression can't be evaluated in that way.

The concept the code had used is called **operator overloading** and it could be used in structs too.

So, there are two methods to achieve this:

1. Define a class member function which compares the private variables members of the class.
2. Or, use operator overloading to define what the operator(s), such as `+`, `<<`, etc. should do when they're used with the corresponding class objects (in that way you've used in the code).